# How can you use Managed Identity authentication and the Blob connector?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

How can you use Managed Identity authentication and the Blob connector?

The blob API Connector only seems to have an option to enter a SAS key, not to use Managed Identity.

I can do "raw HTTP" requests, e.g. [access-to-blob-storage-using-managed-identity-in-logic-apps](https://adatum.no/azure/azure-logic-apps/access-to-blob-storage-using-managed-identity-in-logic-apps), but then I lose all the Blob actions, e.g. "List Blobs".

So is there anyway to have the nice features of the Blob actions, and use Managed Identity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there anyway to have the nice features of the Blob actions, and use Managed Identity?

I test in my site and can use blob action with Managed Identity. You could refer to the following steps to do it.

1.Go to your logic app > `Identity`> turn on `System assigned` Managed Identity.

2.Go to your Storage > `Access control` > `Add role assignment` and add your logic app with `Storage Blob Data Control` role like below:

[image]

3.Then you could list blob in logic app.Use the following designer:

[image]

And the output is as below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. It's very useful ... but you're using the HTTP action. I was asking whether there was any way to use managed identity AND still keep the actions in the "Azure Blob Storage" connector? I appreciate that under the hood, the connector is doing the same HTTP requests you've shown above

Comment: Logic Apps now support system-assigned managed identities allowing you to call web app endpoints using the **HTTP action** with the logic apps managed identity. You could refer to this [issue](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/32499439-add-support-for-managed-service-identity-msi#{toggle_previous_statuses}).

Comment: As a specific example, suppose that you want to run the Snapshot Blob operation on a blob in the Azure Storage account where you previously set up access for your identity. However, **the Azure Blob Storage connector doesn't currently offer this operation. Instead, you can run this operation by using the HTTP action or another Blob Service REST API operation**. Refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-managed-service-identity#authenticate-access-with-managed-identity).

Comment: It helps, but it doesn't actually answer my question "So is there anyway to have the nice features of the Blob actions, and use Managed Identity?" ... you response gives us an alternative. Hence my upvoting your response, but not accepting it as an answer

Comment: As I have said, you can run blob actions with MSI only by using Http action or blob service rest api.